# @font-face not working. I am a novice html & css user

Tags: html, css, font-face

```
 @font-face
   {
    font-family: 'trajan';
    src:
        url ('fonts/trajan.otf'),
        url ('fonts/trajan.eot'),
        url ('fonts/trajan'),
        url ('fonts/trajan.woff'),
        url ('fonts/trajan2'),
        url ('fonts/trajan3');
   }


 #customfont{

    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: trajan;

}
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="customfont">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
</div>
```

---

The font size changes.  It appears that I only have the custom font part messed up.  I have stored the fonts in a folder called 'fonts'

Comment: Are the css file and the fonts folder in the same directory?

Comment: Not sure wether it makes a difference, but you define the font-family with single quotes around trajan, but use it without single quotes in your #customfont. Apart from that, make sure the path to your font files is correct.

Comment: What's your folder structure like. You might just need to go up a directory `../`. But as I say, it depends on the folder structure of the project.

Comment: @NickR Absolute paths would be better still :)

Comment: Well it depends if the page will be in the root directory, or in a folder.

Comment: the css was added to the styles sheet which is burried down in a subset of folders.  But the color/size change, ie: color: black, will change the font to black.

This is a site I purchased from wrapbootstrap.com so the folder structure was already setup.  Index.html is in the main folder, and the fonts folder is that main folder, not within any other folder, its by itself.

Comment: Thanks @milanzor, NickR, and Niet the Dark Absol....wasn't expecting responses this quickly.
VERY appreciated :)

Comment: So, did you fix it? If changing the color works, then your CSS file is loaded and working. If the custom-font doesn't work, it means it the browser is pointed to a wrong location for the font files, all you gotta do is fix that!

Comment: what's this for        `url ('fonts/trajan2'), url ('fonts/trajan3');`

Comment: Posting the folder structure will help us fix your css code

Comment: agreed with @asprin also read this, your code is missing stuff: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: I agree right!!! @milanzor but I have tried everything I can think of
C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Testing Recruitmentdesk.com\fonts\trajan.otf

still nothing

Comment: @user3634897 - your absolute URL will not work, you would have to prefix it with file:// as it is a file on your PC, that will make it work on your PC only though, so don't use it. Tell us your folder structure and we can fix it for you.

Comment: @vlrprbttst trajan2 is .ttf and trajan3 is svg

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the 'folder structure' part.  As I said I'm learning... what is it specifically you are asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t know if it makes any difference, but you have a url without extension ( url ('fonts/trajan') )

Or you might have the path wrong (maybe your CSS is in a folder and you need to go up one folder?).

Anyway, here is a structure that I use for @font-face:

```
/* FONTS */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'trajan';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url('fonts/trajan.eot');
  src: url('fonts/trajan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  src: local('trajan'), url(fonts/trajan.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did use this still no font change tho :(.
The main folder is called testing, the index.html file is in there.  the Fonts folder is in there as well.  style.css is /assets/css/style.css, within the 'testing' folder.
Clearly I'm not referring to the location correctly.  I'm am SO appreciative of the help EVERYONE!

Comment: If I understand correctly:
a) Your fonts path: testing / fonts
b) Your CSS path: testing / assets / css.

If so, your url should be url('../../fonts/trajan.[ext]')